# how to use Google API to get the location based on WiFI MAC Address

Tags: geolocation, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client

I am looking for document and a sample java client program for this to get the user's location (longitude and latitude based on wifi access point MAC address/SSID). However after searching for quite some time, I didn't find the exact documentation for this and a java sample client program.

It would be highly appreciated if someone could point me on the right track here. This is for using at Laptop instead of on smart phone.

I am also looking for similar API for getting the user location by using IP Address as well.

Comment: I saw this link [Google Gear Geolocation](http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/GeolocationAPI), however it is not available any more and it is for web browser. Is there new API for geo location here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obsolete** (preserved for historical reference only!):

---

Gears used the Geolocation Network Protocol and sent the information to the http://www.google.com/loc/json endpoint. The [request format is documented](http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/GeolocationAPI#Request_Format), but the TOS does not permit you to do this as far as I know. It's essentially a non-public API.

Comment: thanks very much. Just wonder how [geosense for windows](http://geosenseforwindows.com/) could do it then. If we want to do same thing, we need to reach out to Google to get the permission to use the API, right?

Comment: Assume yes, contacting Google is necessary here.